# what IS the og:url metatag?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am building an iOS app that is supposed to use openGraph objects for users.
As I see it, I need to :

**1.** create object pages for each of these objects that contains all the metatags that facebook is generating for your created objects in **`Get Code`**.

**2.** Use the iOS app to generate opengraph requests that involve these objects through a single page. ie. a PHP file that uses parameters you might send to it, that would generate links to images and some titles etc... (am I right?)

The thing is that the PHP file on step 2 is supposed to be the object itself, and my object needs a **`og:url`** which is either interpreted as a type:wesite, which is wrong because my type is set to my own custom type! or it just throws an error saying that the og:url is not valid.

I can see that facebook is scraping whatever I give it in the og:url, so basically why is this needed in the first place if all metatags are ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have this correct, basically, to publish an action against an object using the Open Graph APIs, there needs to be an object URL which, when accessed, does one of the following

1. Contains the complete set of metadata needed to describe whatever type of object you're created and serves this to Facebook's crawler
2. Contains an og:url meta tag, a `<link ref="canonical` tag or a HTTP 301 redirect pointing to a URL which does 1)

Having a PHP script which takes input parameters and returns metadata based on those is a common approach, the biggest thing to watch out for is that your og:url tag matches the input parameters, so Facebook's crawler doesn't make a new request out to that URL instead of the one it asked for originally

Answer (score 1):

og:url means: Open Graph Uniform resource locator.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/